# Move strings within a mixed string and float column to new column in Pandas

Tags: pandas

Can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I have a column 'q' within my dataframe that has both strings and floats. I would like to remove the string values from 'q' and move them into an existing string column 'comments'. Any help is appreciated.

I have tried:

```
df['comments']=[isinstance(x, str) for x in df.q]
```

I have also tried some str methods on q but to no avail. Any direction on this would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post a sample of your Dataframe? Are they all strings, but you don't want digits? Are the types actually mixed?

Comment: `s = pd.to_numeric(df.col1, errors='coerce')` gives you a converted list of floats. Then you have `s.isnull().index` the indexes of values you'll transfer to comments. You can do that using `loc`. If you edit with some sample data, gets easier to demonstrate

Comment: Thank you RafaelC. Your answer definitely got me thinking on the right track. I had some issues with the indexing of my df because of concatenation early on, but once I got that straightened out I was able to use your series creation method and use a .loc to work it out.
    
    `s = pd.to_numeric(df.q, errors='coerce')` /n
    `df['comments1'] = df.q.loc[s.isnull()]`

Answer (score 0):

If series is:

```
s=pd.Series([1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,'this','is',1.4,'a',1.5,'comment'])
s
Out[24]: 
0          1
1        1.1
2        1.2
3        1.3
4       this
5         is
6        1.4
7          a
8        1.5
9    comment
dtype: object
```

then only floats can be:

```
[e if type(e) is float else np.NaN for e in s if type(e)]
Out[25]: [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, nan, nan, 1.4, nan, 1.5, nan]
```

And comments can be:

```
[e if type(e) is not float else '' for e in s if type(e)]
Out[26]: ['', '', '', '', 'this', 'is', '', 'a', '', 'comment']
```

This is what you are trying to do.

But element-wise iteration with pandas does not scale well, so extract floats only using:

```
pd.to_numeric(s,errors='coerce')
Out[27]: 
0    1.0
1    1.1
2    1.2
3    1.3
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    1.4
7    NaN
8    1.5
9    NaN
dtype: float64
```

and :

```
pd.to_numeric(s,errors='coerce').to_frame('floats').merge(s.loc[pd.to_numeric(s,errors='coerce').isnull()].to_frame('comments'), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
Out[71]: 
   floats comments
0     1.0      NaN
1     1.1      NaN
2     1.2      NaN
3     1.3      NaN
4     NaN     this
5     NaN       is
6     1.4      NaN
7     NaN        a
8     1.5      NaN
9     NaN  comment
```

there is a side effect to `pd.to_numeric(s,errors='coerce')` where it'll convert all strings with float literals to float instead of keeping it as a string.

```
pd.to_numeric(pd.Series([1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,'this','is',1.4,'a',1.5,'comment','12.345']), errors='coerce')
Out[73]: 
0      1.000
1      1.100
2      1.200
3      1.300
4        NaN
5        NaN
6      1.400
7        NaN
8      1.500
9        NaN
10    12.345   <--- this is now the float 12.345 not str
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to convert strings with float literals into floats, you can use also `str.isnumeric()` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'q':[1.5,2.5,3.5,'a', 'b', 5.1,'3.55','1.44']})

df['comments'] = df.loc[df['q'].str.isnumeric()==False, 'q']

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
      q comments
0   1.5      NaN
1   2.5      NaN
2   3.5      NaN
3     a        a
4     b        b
5   5.1      NaN
6  3.55     3.55  <-- strings are not converted into floats
7  1.44     1.44
```

Or something like this:

```
criterion = df.q.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x,str))
df['comments'] = df.loc[criterion, 'q']
```

Again, it won't convert strings into floats.